# Eevee bloom effect covers my texture as camera gets further away from the object

Tags: rendering, shaders, light, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have a star mesh that has a Texture on it for the mouth, which is just a black curve for a smile. The star's material has a translucent shader and the star has a light inside it, creating a glow effect. However, this causes my mouth to fade out as you move away from the object. Is there a way to stop this from happening? The yellow-mouth material is assigned only to mouth area and the Material is assigned to the rest of the object.[image: The Yellow-mouth material is assigned to the faces of the mesh around where the mouth is located, this is how it looks up close.][image: This is how it looks a little far away.][image: At this point you can barely even see it.][image: This is the shader for the rest of the object.]

Comment: One way is to use 2 render layers with one dedicated to overlay the mouth over the glow effect.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Not yet. How would I do this exactly in blender 2.8?

Comment: Sorry but you will have to do some research and learning about this https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html . I would have your base scene, just modified without the smile, then on the second layer, paint your smile on a separate texture so that only the smile appears on the render, then use Compositing to simply add it to the original bloomed render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK a few mn to spare to take a crack at it:

The basic concept is to render the smile on a separate layer and overlay it over the bloom effect using Compositing.

In this example, I used a curve instead of a texture for the smile. A texture could still be used as long as it is rendered with some transparency around the smile.

1. Remove the smile texture from the star material
2. Check the `Film/Transparent` box, this allows to do compositing properly
   [image]
3. Create your smile using a curve and beveling it. Use a black emission shader. Parent it to the start
4. Create a 2nd Layer just for the Smile. We'll use this collection to render only the smile in the second layer
   [image]
5. Make sure to enable `Environment` on your main render Layer
   [image]
6. Create a second render layer and disable the main collection, leaving just the Smile collection enabled.
   [image]
7. Composite the environment and the two layers using `Alpha over` nodes
   [image]

Now the smile should remain visible no matter how far the star is or how strong the bloom is. Note that since the composite effect is only applied at render time, the Viewport bloom will still cover the smile if the star is far away.

[image]

Comment: Wow that was really helpful. Thank you!